# Make background images fadein onload and disappear when you open an accordion tab

Tags: javascript, css, background-image, fadein, onload

I am working with this website and I added two background images that cross fade. Here is the link: [www.alexarodulfo.com](http://www.johnfitzphoto.com/sofi/ALEXA/home.html). 
However, I wanted to see if:
1) It is possible to make the fade in more subtle, like they actually fade slowly onload and when they overlap one another.
2) It is possible to make them disappear whenever you open an accordion tab on the menu and make them appear again when they are all closed.
This is the code that I am using for the background images fade in:

```
<style>

body{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 200 100;}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
// (C) 2006 CodeLifter.com

var speed = 6000;
var crossFadeDuration = 10;
var Pic = new Array();

Pic[0] = 'images/back_2.png';
Pic[1] = 'images/back_1.png';

var t;
var j = 0;
var p = Pic.length;

var preLoad = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < p; i++){
   preLoad[i] = new Image();
   preLoad[i].src = Pic[i];}

function runSlideShow(){

if (document.all){
    document.body.style.filter="blendTrans(duration=crossFadeDuration)";
    document.body.filters.blendTrans.Apply();
    document.body.filters.blendTrans.Play();}  

if (document.body){
    document.body.background = Pic[j];    
    j = j + 1
    if (j > (p-1)) j=0
    t = setTimeout('runSlideShow()', speed)}    

} 
</script>

</head>

<body onload="runSlideShow()"></body>
</head>
```

Thanks!
Sophie

Comment: this is IE only code, not a very good thing to start with.
For a simple slideshow you would be better of taking a look at the jquery cycle plugin to create a nice fading effect between images. It has loads of examples too.

Comment: ok you are def right i found an easier one with jquery cycle plug in:`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
  fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
 });
});
</script>` My problem was: how to make the images the background without causing problems to everything else. @HanDijik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to structure your site differently you could use z-index and stack the images behind your content but not set as the background image. You can just place them in a div.

Answer (score 0):

Using separate div and overlapping them with z-index it actually worked. I added the Jquery Cycle plug in:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is the link: [fade in background](http://www.johnfitzphoto.com/sofi/ALEXA/home.html)